# how can i do a rank with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an id and a value.
How can I rank an element of the table in order desc by its value?
What I want to do is:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY value DESC
```

And i want it to tell me for exemple the position of id=4

thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not have analytic functions, so you have to use [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT   @r:=@r+1 AS rank, id
FROM     table, (SELECT @r:=0) init
ORDER BY value DESC
```

To get the rank of a particular record, wrap it in an outer query:

```
SELECT rank FROM (
  SELECT   @r:=@r+1 AS rank, id
  FROM     table, (SELECT @r:=0) init
  ORDER BY value DESC
) t WHERE id = 4
```

To save MySQL from needlessly calculating the rank of *every* record in the table, you could add a filter:

```
SELECT rank FROM (
  SELECT   @r:=@r+1 AS rank, table.id
  FROM     table,
           (SELECT value FROM table WHERE id=4) t,
           (SELECT @r:=0) init
  WHERE    table.value >= t.value
  ORDER BY table.value DESC
) t WHERE id = 4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @eggyal, so in php should I do :

$test = $bdd->query('SELECT   @r:=@r+1 AS rank, id
FROM     table, (SELECT @r:=0) init
ORDER BY value DESC');
$tk = $test->fetch();
echo '' . $tk[@r] . '';

Comment: @user1754181: Yes, you could do that (but the column name in the resultset will be `rank`, not `@r`, due to the alias).  But if you have no need for the rank value within your SQL, you could simply generate it whilst looping over the resultset in PHP and save yourself all of this fuss.

Comment: I tried, but it tells me "Use of undefined constant rank - assumed 'rank'"

Comment: @user1754181: Well, yes, just like any other column name it's a string that needs to be quoted as such: `$tk['rank']`.

Comment: but @eggyal how should i do now, for exemple to have the rank of id=4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Eggyal's solution is not a `rank`, but a `row_number` (these actually have meaning because they are part of the SQL standard).

I think the following does a `dense_rank` in MySQL:

```
SELECT   @r:=@r+1 AS rank, id
FROM     (select id, count(*) as cnt
          from table t
          group by id
         ),
         (SELECT @r:=0) init
ORDER BY value DESC
```

A `rank` is a bit harder . . . I think the following will work:

```
SELECT   @r:=@r+1-offset AS rank, id
FROM     (select id, count(*) as cnt
          from table t
          group by id
         ),
         (SELECT @r:=0, count(*)-1 as offset
          from table t
          group by id
          order by count(*) desc
          limit 1
         ) init
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff, but I still don't get what should I do to have the rank of id=4 ?